# git: Resetting/rebasing sub-repositories in a monorepository

Tags: git, llvm, monorepo

**

> Installation:
>   To get the right version of LLVM and clang follow the instructions to install from git and then rebase both to the specified versions.
>   LLVM fa840e7dfb9115a3ac9891d898e7fe2543c65948 
>   clang 3e24ceaa26f9e1cbd67fdc8625f07bfcc9977053

**

Hi,
I've been trying to follow the above instructions to build llvm and clang from source code. The source code repo is one unified project which has llvm, clang and additional sub-projects. I'm having difficulty trying to figure out how to rebase/revert/reset the individual sub-repositories to specified hashes. I get "fatal: Needed a single revision" or "fatal: Could not parse object 'fa840e7dfb9115a3ac9891d898e7fe2543c65948'." if i try to rebase or reset it respectively.
Not sure if i am doing it right.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the hashes are from old "per-module" git mirrors. The hashes in the monorepo are different. You may probably need to find the corresponding SVN revisions to obtain new hashes